# libinput -- disable horizontal scrolling

Tags: libinput, mouse-gestures

The Logitech Trackman does not have a scroll wheel so we enable it by installing libinput and this libinput.conf

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier   "Marble Mouse"
MatchProduct "Logitech USB Trackball"
Driver       "libinput"
Option       "ScrollMethod"    "button"
Option       "ScrollButton"    "8"
Option       "MiddleEmulation" "true"
EndSection
```

This works well. Combining small-left button with a vertical ball roll  scrolls the page vertically but if there is an active horizontal scroll bar the page jitters. A perfectly straight roll requires precise movement and I never need a horizontal scroll.

The libinput documentation has this to say

```
Horizontal scrolling
Scroll movements provide vertical and horizontal directions,
 each scroll event contains both directions where applicable, 
 see libinput_event_pointer_get_axis_value(). 
 libinput does not provide separate toggles to enable or disable
 horizontal scrolling. Instead, horizontal scrolling is always enabled. 
 This is intentional, libinput does not have enough context to know when
 horizontal scrolling is appropriate for a given widget. 
 The task of filtering horizontal movements is up to the caller.
```

Here's the rub:

**libinput does not provide separate toggles to enable or disable
horizontal scrolling.... The task of filtering horizontal movements is up to the caller.**

Who is the 'caller' here and how could I configure the caller to drop horizontal movements.

Comment: The caller is the application reading the mouse events. It might be your GUI or a particular application. Just like `libinput` doesn't have enough context to decide if horizontal scrolling is appropriate, we don't have enough context to find out how to disable it. Can you provide more information on your GUI and the application you'd like to have it disabled in in case it cannot be globally disabled?

Comment: Thanks. MATE/Marco(Adaptive Compositor) on Arch, applications: brave browser,libreoffice writer, generally any application presenting a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you. `Option       "HorizontalScrolling" "false"' does the trick. I see now that the documentation I was looking at is for **wayland** libinput. https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/scrolling.html. Google took me there first. The link you posted took me to the Xorg libinput man page.